# How to get all the filenames from a directory using ant

Tags: ant

Using ant I want to get all the filenames from a directory and create a property with value as comma separated file names.

Example: If we have 3 files in a directory (i.e. 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) then we have to create  a property & its value should be 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt.

Thanks,
Mansoor MD.

Comment: What's your end goal? What do you want to do with this property?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to create a path with the files:

```
<path>
    <fileset dir="${dir.name}">
          <include name="*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This can be combined with a `<pathconvert>` task:

```
<pathconvert pathsep=","
    property="my.files">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${dir.name}">
            <include name="*"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
</pathconvert>
```

The property `${my.files}` will contain a comma separated list of files.

If you prefer, you can do this in two steps:

```
<path id="mypath">
    <fileset dir="${dir.name}">
          <include name="*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<pathconvert pathsep=","
    property="my.files"
    refid="mypath"/>
```

***Word 'o Warning***: It will also contain the **full path** to these files.